# About having a subdomain to stackoverflow

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to build my own XXXX.stackoverflow.com Q&A?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158351/how-to-build-my-own-xxxx-stackoverflow-com-qa)

I have seen facebook.stackoverflow.com which is a facebook section in stack overflow. Is this some special stuff made for facebook, or can anyone create their own "section" in stackover flow..

The thing is, we are running a site called www.getshop.com and would like to start using stackoverflow to answer questions people have about it.

Is it possible to get getshop.stackoverflow.com ?

Comment: What does this have to do with programming? It sounds like you want to use Stack Overflow as a general support forum, which is highly discouraged. P.S. the features page of your website is blank...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, im just checking out all posibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Nope not possible.

Goto Area51 and suggest an SE if you want.

Or just make a tag [getshop](/questions/tagged/getshop) and have people ask/answer questions using that tag.

Comment: If you have to create the tag yourself because no one has ever asked a question about your service, you're probably no Facebook.

Comment: @Wooble hehe that too :-P although `facebook.stackoverflow.com` is just a portal to [tag:facebook] questions.