# Are more mini-sites coming?

Tags: discussion, support, mini-site

I was wondering if there are any plans to implement more mini-sites like the Facebook one, or something similar.  I'm hoping that we'll see topic-specific sites (as opposed to necessarily company-specific), as Pekka lines out in the referenced link below.

Related:

[Is it time to re-evaluate the Facebook-Stack Overflow partnership?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121547/is-it-time-to-re-evaluate-the-facebook-stack-overflow-partnership)

[Introduce sub-communities (or “Portals”) to prevent fragmentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94591/introduce-sub-communities-or-portals-to-prevent-fragmentation)

Comment: There was also supposed to be [a mini-site of Skeptics for political fact-checking](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1754/electioncheck-a-political-subsite-a-mockup), but we haven't heard anything about it in over six months. (Possibly because it overlaps with the new Politics.SE? They never said.)

Comment: Funny, someone else [asked about getting a mini-site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158475/about-having-a-subdomain-to-stackoverflow) about a half hour before you. Anyways, the answer to your question is no, [according to Anna Lear](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158353/131713).

Comment: Not funny, that question got me thinking.  I'm more interested in non-company (i.e. topic) specific sites as Pekka was referring to in his post.

Comment: It's really a shame and a half that [tag:facebook] was the first implementation chosen for this idea, because AFAICT Facebook the company totally screwed the pooch by trying to send non-developer support over here too. Now it looks like SE is gunshy about trying it again, when in fact picking a different topic ([tag:PHP] or [tag:C++], e.g.) which already has a strong community could make this a success and contribute to the overall site.

Comment: God no, I hope not.  It just doesn't work well for us.

Comment: I realize that the facebook one didn't work well, but why don't you think that a topical one won't?

Comment: @Casper: It _didn't_ work well, but something other than opening a new fire hydrant of idiots to be absorbed by an unprepared site (with no existing sub-community for the topic) might. To strain my own metaphor, there exist wells, aquifers, and ponds with potable water on SO already -- building pumping stations to make them easier to access seems like a good idea to me.

Comment: @NickStauner no it's not.

Comment: @ShadowWizard How isn't it?

Comment: @michaelb958 The other question is about constructing one's own site. This question is about mini-sites

Comment: @michael oops, thought the other one asked about using the engine. My bad, it was late at night! Hammer used to close.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: FWIW, you made me second-guess my flag, and I see an argument for reopening. The other one is practically a feature request (that doesn't know it's asking for something not implemented), whereas this one is asking about what the in-house plan for mini-sites is. I guess the answer is pretty much the same either way though.

Comment: @NickStauner both about the same thing and Anna's response is official: no such sites are planned. Hmm... no indication of hammer.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Why are you editing out [tag:mini-site]? It appears to be an on-topic concept that is useful to group by.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Mini-sites aren't implemented anymore.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: That's irrelevant; they *could* be reimplemented in principle, and ungrouping all the relevant old posts, or occasional new posts about the same concept, does no one any favors at all.

Answer (score 10):

The impression I've got is that the idea of subsites had been abandoned for the forseeable future, at least in this specific form. I asked an SE employee about the future of subsites some months ago, and the response was pretty negative on future subsites happening the same way as Facebook.

Comment: Makes me wonder if the answer would have been different had Facebook actually decided to contribute employee answers.  Last I checked, they *still* weren't.

Comment: Yeah Facebook didn't really live up to their side of the bargain with the community, did they?